# Get next three elements in a coldfusion list

Tags: list, coldfusion

I have a list like this for example, 7141,6881,5821,8001,7904,6601,7961,6021,4721 where each is the id of a employee. I have a page which has employee description, and a next button on it. On clicking next I need to get the next employees details doing it like below.

```
<cfset getempls(arguments.id) />

    <cfset local.emp_id_list = valueList(VARIABLES.employee.emp_id) />
    <cfset emp_index = listFind(local.emp_id_list, arguments.emp_id) />
    <cfset local.emp_id = "" />
    <cfif emp_index LT VARIABLES.employee.recordcount>
        <cfset local.emp_id = listGetAt(local.emp_id_list, emp_index + 1) />
    </cfif>
```

I also need to grab preview of next 3 employees on the detail page, meaning, on the detail page of emp_ID 7141, I need to show 6881,5821,8001 details too; need to go through the list till the end. Can anyone suggest a best way to do this. I did something like below, but I need this to work even if the list has less than 3 employees. Any thoughts? thanks

```
     <cfif listlen(local.emp_id_list) eq 3> 
            <cfset local.next_three_emp_id_list = listappend(local.next_3_emp_id_list, listGetAt(local.emp_id_list, emp_index + 2)) />  
            <cfset local.next_three_emp_id_list = listappend(local.next_three_emp_id_list, listGetAt(local.emp_id_list, emp_index + 3)) />
        </cfif>
```

Comment: It would be easier to do this with an array. You could utilize the array index as offset. You can convert your list using the `listToArray` function.

Comment: I would be tempted to load the list into an array and put that array into a session variable. I would then push the current index, rather than the whole list

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: What else is contained in the query variables.employee?

Answer (score 1):

While I generally try to avoid using session variables, this might be a situation where it's appropriate.

On the first page, change:

```
<cfquery name = "employee">
```

to

```
<cfquery name = "session.employee">
```

then do this:

```
<cfoutput query = "session.employee">
<a href=page2.cfm?row=#rownumber#">somethigng</a>
```

on page2.cfm do this:

```
<cfoutput query = "session.employee" startrow = url.row maxrows="3">
display code
```

Answer (score 0):

One should never use a list when one has an array to start with (well: one should just not use lists where at all possible). With this in mind, [here's a solution](https://gist.github.com/adamcameron/4844026b3ecfe8fa2a15) that deals with arrays of IDs, not lists of IDs.

```
<cfscript>
function nextIds(ids, id, count){
    var thisIdIdx = ids.find(id);
    var idsLen = ids.len();
    if (thisIdIdx == 0 || thisIdIdx == idsLen){
        return [];
    }
    return ids.slice(thisIdIdx+1, min(idsLen-thisIdIdx, count));
}
</cfscript>
```